# How do you create a simple webservice in mule and accept data from a mobile app?

Tags: web-services, mule

Apologies as I am new to the webservice space.  I would like to ask some guidance on how to create a webservice that will receive data from a mobile app (XML or JSON). It will just be a simple call and Inwould need the data to be inserted to our database. I can manage to deal with the DB and the actual flow and my issue is more on how to create the actual webservice from Mule. and thought examples and comment will be appreciated.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating web-services in Mule is pretty easy to implement and start consuming.

You can go through these links to give you a good headstart: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/building-web-services-with-cxf

And you can play with this project:
https://github.com/marcotello/MuleESB/tree/master/simplecxfservice

However, as you mention you know something about the mule components and flows, you'll have to do transformation of your XML/JSON input received from the mobile App to be able to be saved in Database properly.

Answer (score 2):

To accept requests from mobile applications - create light weight rest APIs that consume JSON payload over the http protocol.

There are various frameworks to create rest APIs. To develop rest APIs using mule follow:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/rest-api-examples

Once you create a rest API, use a JSON-Object transformer with a return type of java.util.map to access each of the fields in the JSON payload. 
Check out the available transformers at the below mentioned link.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/transformers

Comment: To be precise JSON To Object transformer can be used as mentioned above to extract the element values from JSON and the return type may be `java.util.HashMap` or `java.util.Map` or `java.util.List` depends on the JSON.. We can also use `java.lang.Object` to parse the JSON to extract values